# Temperature Scale in SA

Tags: simulated-annealing

First, this is not a question about temperature iteration counts or automatically optimized scheduling. It's how the data magnitude relates to the scaling of the exponentiation.

I'm using the classic formula:

```
if(delta < 0 || exp(-delta/tK) > random()) { // new state }
```

The input to the exp function is negative because delta/tK is positive, so the exp result is always less then 1. The random function also returns a value in the 0 to 1 range.

My test data is in the range 1 to 20, and the delta values are below 20. I pick a start temperature equal to the initial computed temperature of the system and linearly ramp down to 1.

In order to get SA to work, I have to scale tK. The working version uses:

```
exp(-delta/(tK * .001)) > random()
```

So how does the magnitude of tK relate to the magnitude of delta? I found the scaling factor by trial and error, and I don't understand why it's needed. To my understanding, as long as delta > tK and the step size and number of iterations are reasonable, it should work. In my test case, if I leave out the extra scale the temperature of the system does not decrease.

The various online sources I've looked at say nothing about working with real data. Sometimes they include the Boltzmann constant as a scale, but since I'm not simulating a physical particle system that doesn't help. Examples (typically with pseudocode) use values like 100 or 1000000.

So what am I missing? Is scaling another value that I must set by trial and error? It's bugging me because I don't just want to get this test case running, I want to understand the algorithm, and magic constants mean I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Classical SA has 2 parameters: startingTemperate and cooldownSchedule (= what you call scaling).

Configuring 2+ parameters is annoying, so [in OptaPlanner's implementation](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/impl/localsearch/decider/acceptor/simulatedannealing/SimulatedAnnealingAcceptor.java), I automatically calculate the cooldownSchedule based on the timeGradiant (which is a double going from 0.0 to 1.0 during the solver time). This works well. As a guideline for the startingTemperature, I use the maximum score diff of a single move. For more information, see [the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html).